# wrong number of arguments for custom chef provider/resource/recipes

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am trying to write custom resource and provider to configure splunk files.

Following are the code for resource / provider/ recipe :

### splunk/recipes/default.rb

```
Chef::Log.info "Creating directory /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/apps/myapps/"
directory "/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/apps/myapps/" do
    action :create
end

splunk_monitor "/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/apps/myapps/apache.conf"  do
  monitoring_path         "/logs/logsw0/access_log"
  source_type             "combined_log"
  whitelist               "access"
  index                   "web"
  ignore_older_than       "15d"
  file_path               "/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/apps/myapps/apache.conf"
  action                  :create
end
```

### splunk/resources/monitor.rb

```
provides :monitor
actions :create
default_action :create

attribute :name, :kind_of => String, :required => true
attribute :monitoring_path, :kind_of =>  String,  :required => true
attribute source_type, :kind_of => String, :required => true
attribute :whitelist, :kind_of => String , :required => true
attribute :index, :kind_of => String, :required => true
attribute :ignore_older_than, :kind_of => String, :required => true
attr_accessor :name, :monitoring_path , ource_type, :whitelist , :index, :ignore_older_than
```

### splunk/providers/monitor.rb

```
action :create do
template  new_resource.name  do
    source 'input.conf.erb'
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode  0644
    variables ( {
            "monitoring_path" => new_resource.monitoring_path,
            "whitelist" => new_resource.whitelist,
            "index" => new_resource.index,
            "source_type" => new_resource.source_type,
            "ignore_older_than" => new_resource.ignore_older_than
           }        )
    end

    new_resource.updated_by_last_action(true)
end
```

It throws the given error while running chef solo. chef solo version is 11.12.8.

### Error

```
========================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /home/rjain/cookbooks/splunk/recipes/default.rb
============================================================================


ArgumentError
-------------
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/home/rjain/cookbooks/splunk/recipes/default.rb:7:in `block in from_file'
/home/rjain/cookbooks/splunk/recipes/default.rb:6:in `from_file'
```

I tried to figure this out in my code by comparing [apt](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apt) provider/resource, But still no luck. 
Could anyone suggest what's wrong in code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be missing a colon in the resource:

```
attribute source_type, :kind_of => String, :required => true
```

Should read:

```
attribute :source_type, :kind_of => String, :required => true
```

Comment: Thanks Martin for your valuable inputs. I corrected this error in code but didnt fix the issue. I found that in splunk/resource/monitor.rb file I was defining attributes as attr_accessor which was causing the issue. After commenting  this line it got sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing a 'file_path' parameter in your resource but your resource call sets it. Also, as Martin said source_type should be :source_type and in your attr_accessors list ource_type should be :source_type.